# How to extract the substring from the String using StringTokenizer in Java?

Tags: java

Following is the source string. And I need to extract the values from this string.

```
String str = "sid=2096349073&name=Sam_Michaels";
```

For example, I should get the token value as "2096349073" and next token should be "Sam_Michaels"

Comment: Do you have to use StringTokenizer? What did you try?

Comment: Use a regex to do it?

Comment: Do you have a simple script for it please?

Comment: As I asked before: Do you have to use StringTokenizer? What did you try?

Comment: Its not necessary to use StringTokenizer, but I am having n number of lines in file of such type of strings and I need to get only the values.

Comment: @AngieRussell - Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks like a *give me the codez* question

Answer (score 1):

***You don't need StringTokenizer.***  This will work same

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "sid=2096349073&name=Sam_Michaels";
        String id=str.substring(1+str.indexOf("="),str.indexOf("&"));
        String name=str.substring(1+str.lastIndexOf("="));
        System.out.println("Id is : "+id);
        System.out.println("name is : "+name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shivam, it perfectly works :)

Comment: I was wondering that using String for the large file would be inefficient as substring causes the complete duplication in String pool. So, I am thinking to migrate using StringBuilder. What do you say?

Comment: @Angie if it works,either accept or vote up the answer.